# Can Stripe make both charge and transfer money to customer object?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments

I'm building a system and integrated with Stripe API for creating payments(charge) and transfer money to customer later.

Firstly, we will validate their credit card using stripe api and then using the Stripe Token get from credit card submitted to create `Customer Object`. This will let us charge the customer at any point in the future.(Stripe Charge API [details](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges))

And we also want to transfer money to customer later but there is no payment before. That means my system can charge money to customer A and transfer money to both A and B without knowing have or haven't payment before. -> We have to use the Stripe `Transfers` API.

But the Transfer API required the `recipient Object` with details (a bank account or a debit card).(Stripe Transfer API [details](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers))  Does Stripe allows transfers from `Customer Object` which we created before ?

All things we want is the user just submit their credit card one time and system can make both charge and transfer money later. Is it possible in stripe API to make both charge and transfer money?

Answer (score 0):

You can only charge customers.

You can send money to Stripe account but only in certain use cases. The case for sending money in Stripe requires that the recipient (the stripe account), gets the money as a direct result as a charge, the most you can do is without the transfer to the bank account (you cannot withhold the transfer to their stripe account). Stripe documents this via the Stripe Connect feature and documentation.